# Login and Register app not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, neo4j, neoeloquent

I wrote a simple Login/Registration code in laravel with neo4j as DB. I installed `vinelab/neoeloquent` in my project, created a simple model to store the registration data in neo4j DB:
`app/models/Reg.php`

```
<?php

class Reg extends NeoEloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('name', 'email', 'password');

    public function index($name, $email, $password, $password_confirm) {

        $formData = Neo4j::makeNode();
        $formData->setProperty('names',$name)
        ->setProperty('email',$mail)
        ->setProperty('password',$pword)
        ->setProprty('password_confirmation',$pword_repeat)
        ->save();

    }

}
```

Here is my `register.blade.php`

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'register.store', 'method' => 'post')) }}

<p>
    {{ Form::text('email', '', array('placeholder' => 'Email')) }}
</p>

<p>
    {{ Form::password('password',  array('placeholder' => 'Password')) }}
</p>

<p>
    {{ Form::password('password_confirmation', array('placeholder' => 'Repeat password')) }}
</p>

<p>
    {{ Form::text('names', '', array('placeholder' => 'Names')) }}
</p>

<p>
    {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
</p>

{{ Form::close() }}

@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
<div>
    {{ $error }}
</div>
@endforeach
```

But the data doesn't get stored in neo4j DB. It returns error, like something gone wrong. Even login functionality isn't working:
`login.blade.php`

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'login.check', 'method' => 'post')) }}
<p>
    {{ Form::text('email', '', array('placeholder' => 'Email')) }}
</p>

<p>
    {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password')) }}
</p>

<p>
    {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
</p>
{{ Form::close() }}

@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
<div>
    {{ $error }}
</div>
@endforeach
```

`Routes.php`

```
<?php

Route::get('register', array(
    'as' => 'register.create',
    'uses' => 'Register@create'
));

Route::post('register', array(
    'as' => 'register.store',
    'uses' => 'Register@store'
));

Route::get('login', array(
    'as' => 'login.form',
    'uses' => 'Login@form'
));

Route::post('login', array(
    'as' => 'login.check',
    'uses' => 'Login@check'
));

Route::get('logout', array(
    'as' => 'logout',
    'uses' => 'Login@logout'
));

Route::get('user/home', array(
    'as' => 'user.home', function() {
        return View::make('home');
    }
));
```

`Errors:`

```
[2015-01-28 07:17:17] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php:5738
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5060): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5048): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5040): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(715): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(696): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(7812): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8419): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8366): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(11029): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#11 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/server.php(19): require_once('/home/ajay/Desk...')
#12 {main} [] []
[2015-01-28 07:17:20] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php:5738
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5060): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5048): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5040): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(715): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(696): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(7812): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8419): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8366): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(11029): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#11 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/server.php(19): require_once('/home/ajay/Desk...')
#12 {main} [] []
[2015-01-28 07:17:22] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php:5738
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5060): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5048): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5040): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(715): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(696): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(7812): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8419): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8366): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(11029): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#11 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/server.php(19): require_once('/home/ajay/Desk...')
#12 {main} [] []
[2015-01-28 07:20:32] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 3 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor, null given, called in /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 7013 and defined' in /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:221
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(221): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(4096, 'Argument 3 pass...', '/home/ajay/Desk...', 221, Array)
#1 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(7013): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__construct(Object(Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Connection), Object(Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Query\Grammars\CypherGrammar), NULL)
#2 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(6978): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#3 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(6989): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQuery()
#4 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(6840): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
#5 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/app/controllers/Register.php(25): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()
#6 [internal function]: Register->store()
#7 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5834): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('store', Array)
#9 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5822): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(Register), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'store')
#10 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5027): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'Register', 'store')
#11 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#12 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5385): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#13 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5052): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5040): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(715): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(696): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(7812): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#18 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8419): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#19 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8366): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#20 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(11029): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#21 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#23 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/server.php(19): require_once('/home/ajay/Desk...')
#24 {main} [] []
[2015-01-28 07:33:34] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS)' in /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/app/storage/views/03cd328e32fa32d624bfa2a91506be61:5
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
[2015-01-28 07:42:45] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 3 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor, null given, called in /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 7013 and defined' in /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:221
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(221): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(4096, 'Argument 3 pass...', '/home/ajay/Desk...', 221, Array)
#1 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(7013): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__construct(Object(Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Connection), Object(Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Query\Grammars\CypherGrammar), NULL)
#2 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(6978): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#3 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(6989): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQuery()
#4 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(6840): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
#5 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/app/controllers/Register.php(25): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()
#6 [internal function]: Register->store()
#7 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5834): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('store', Array)
#9 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5822): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(Register), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'store')
#10 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5027): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'Register', 'store')
#11 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#12 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5385): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#13 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5052): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5040): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(715): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(696): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(7812): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#18 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8419): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#19 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8366): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#20 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(11029): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#21 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#23 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/server.php(19): require_once('/home/ajay/Desk...')
#24 {main} [] []
[2015-01-28 07:43:16] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 3 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor, null given, called in /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 7013 and defined' in /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:221
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(221): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(4096, 'Argument 3 pass...', '/home/ajay/Desk...', 221, Array)
#1 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(7013): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__construct(Object(Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Connection), Object(Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Query\Grammars\CypherGrammar), NULL)
#2 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(6978): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#3 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php(87): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQuery()
#4 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php(354): Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider->retrieveByCredentials(Array)
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Auth\Guard->attempt(Array)
#6 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8287): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(3259): Illuminate\Support\Manager->__call('attempt', Array)
#8 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(3259): Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager->attempt(Array)
#9 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/app/controllers/Login.php(15): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('attempt', Array)
#10 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/app/controllers/Login.php(15): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::attempt(Array)
#11 [internal function]: Login->check()
#12 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5834): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('check', Array)
#14 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5822): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(Login), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'check')
#15 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5027): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'Login', 'check')
#16 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#17 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5385): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#18 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5052): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(5040): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(715): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(696): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(7812): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#23 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8419): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#24 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(8366): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#25 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(11029): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#26 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/bootstrap/compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#28 /home/ajay/Desktop/laravelprojects/login-regform/server.php(19): require_once('/home/ajay/Desk...')
#29 {main} [] []
```

How can I fix the errors?

Comment: Please include your errors in your question

Comment: Here are the errors: http://pastebin.com/f71yRGKJ

Comment: You can edit your question to include the errors directly. It is always preferred to have a valid question containing all information without off-site ressources

Comment: Okay, I'll add the errors to the question

Comment: Can you please add the Register and Login controllers code at exactly where you're using the model to store data ?